# Issues with enpoint mapper service

Tags: vpn, ipsec

In short, we have a VPN server and an AD server.

The VPN server is our connection to a remote AD server. From the VPN server, I can use port query to verify that port 135 is not filtered and it returns all of the endpoints on the remote AD server.

However, when I try to do the same from our AD server, it fails showing the port as filtered.

To verify that it wasn't a firewall issue, I opened up the firewall completely (temporarily) and no luck. This isn't the end of the world, but is causing errors with AD replication.

I know that I have to be missing something obvious, so any input would be helpful. If you need any information from me, just let me know.

Thanks in advance!